Inserting unique attribute to HML tag element in loop
I have a supersite that uses all kinds of js, including backbone.js and underscore.js. On one of my pages, I have the piece of code below:
<#loop:main_tlds_price_add#>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Domains" id="<#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].classkey /#>">
         .<#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].name /#>
      </td>
      <#loop:main_tlds_price_add[].price#>
      <td data-label=""> <#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].price[] /#></td>
          <#/loop:main_tlds_price_add[].price#>
  </tr>
<#/loop:main_tlds_price_add#>

The output of this looks like
<tr>
   <td>.co.uk</td>
   <td>£2.32</td>
   <td>£4.32</td>
   <td>£5.32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>.com</td>
   <td>£2.32</td>
   <td>£14.32</td>
   <td>£50.32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>.ads</td>
   <td>£12.32</td>
   <td>£14.32</td>
   <td>£25.32</td>
</tr>

But what I want is something like this with the new attribute "data-label" injected into the td tag in the loop, as shown below:
<tr>
   <td data-label="tld">.co.uk</td>
   <td data-label="1 year">£2.32</td>
   <td data-label="2 years">£4.32</td>
   <td data-label="5 years">£5.32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td data-label="tld">.com</td>
   <td data-label="1 year">£2.32</td>
   <td data-label="2 years">£14.32</td>
   <td data-label="5 years">£50.32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td data-label="tld">.ads</td>
   <td data-label="1 year">£12.32</td>
   <td data-label="2 years">£14.32</td>
   <td data-label="5 years">£25.32</td>
</tr>

I have thought and researched JS, but my knowledge of JS doesn't go that far.
I hope someone can help out.

"The output of this looks like" - what, so not even the static data-label="Domains" part from the template "survived"?

What library is rendering the templates for you? The template language doesn't look familiar to me.

@Julian it appears to be an in-house template

After several rookie attempts such as:
<#loop:main_tlds_price_add#>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var n = 0; var dynamicYear = ['5 Years','1 Year', '2 Years'];
   </script>
   <tr>
      <td data-label="Domains" id="<#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].classkey /#>">
         .<#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].name /#>
      </td>
      <#loop:main_tlds_price_add[].price#>
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
         $("[data-label='']").attr('data-label', dynamicYear[n]);n++;
      </script>
      <td data-label=""> <#tag:main_tlds_price_add[].price[] /#></td>
      <#/loop:main_tlds_price_add[].price#>
   </tr>
<#/loop:main_tlds_price_add#>

which produced the result I wanted, I managed to refine it as shown below:
<script type="text/javascript">
    // non-dynamic header element
    const nonDynamicElements = ['1 Year', '2 Years', '5 Years'];

    // Function to inject non-dynamic elements into the table
    function injectNonDynamicElements(containerId, elements) {
        // Get the container
        const container = document.getElementById(containerId);

        // Get all rows in the container
        const rows = container.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

        // Loop through each row
        rows.forEach(row => {
            // Get all <td> elements within the row with the placeholder
            const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td[data-label=""]');

            // Ensure there are enough non-dynamic elements to match the generated elements
            if (tds.length !== elements.length) {
                console.error('The number of generated elements does not match the number of non-dynamic elements.');
            } else {
                // Loop through the generated <td> elements and inject the non-dynamic elements
                tds.forEach((td, index) => {
                    td.setAttribute('data-label', elements[index]);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    // Call the function for the table with id 'priceTable'
    injectNonDynamicElements('priceTable', nonDynamicElements);
</script>

